# Web pack bundle 16-es2015.4841415d71ce63224674.js: Unexpected token ','

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, build, babeljs

While taking a build of an ionic-angular project it shows this error when optimization is set to true.
These are my angular.json config.
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"extractCss": true,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,

This happens after I run  ionic build --prod which produces this
[error] SyntaxError: D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\16-es2015.4841415d71ce63224674.js: Unexpected token ','. (1:505961).

```
[39m_unsubscribe[33m=[39munsubscribe)}[36mvar[39m empty[33m;[39m[36mreturn[39m [33mSubscription[39m[33m.[39mprototype[33m.[39munsubscribe[33m=[39m[36mfunction[39m(){[36mvar[39m errors[33m;[39m[36mif[39m([33m![39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39mclosed){[36mvar[39m _parentOrParents[33m=[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_parentOrParents[33m,[39m_unsubscribe[33m=[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_unsubscribe[33m,[39m_subscriptions[33m=[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_subscriptions[33m;[39m[36mif[39m([36mthis[39m[33m.[39mclosed[33m=[39m[33m![39m[35m0[39m[33m,[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_parentOrParents[33m=[39m[36mnull[39m[33m,[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_subscriptions[33m=[39m[36mnull[39m[33m,[39m_parentOrParents [36minstanceof[39m [33mSubscription[39m)_parentOrParents[33m.[39mremove([36mthis[39m)[33m;[39m[36melse[39m [36mif[39m([36mnull[39m[33m!==[39m_parentOrParents)[36mfor[39m([36mvar[39m index[33m=[39m[35m0[39m[33m;[39mindex[33m<[39m_parentOrParents[33m.[39mlength[33m;[39m[33m++[39mindex){_parentOrParents[index][33m.[39mremove([36mthis[39m)}[36mif[39m(isFunction_1[33m.[39misFunction(_unsubscribe))[36mtry[39m{_unsubscribe[33m.[39mcall([36mthis[39m)}[36mcatch[39m(e){errors[33m=[39me [36minstanceof[39m [33mUnsubscriptionError_1[39m[33m.[39m[33mUnsubscriptionError[39m[33m?[39mflattenUnsubscriptionErrors(e[33m.[39merrors)[33m:[39m[e]}[36mif[39m(isArray_1[33m.[39misArray(_subscriptions)){index[33m=[39m[33m-[39m[35m1[39m[33m;[39m[36mfor[39m([36mvar[39m len[33m=[39m_subscriptions[33m.[39mlength[33m;[39m[33m++[39mindex[33m<[39m[33mlen[39m[33m;[39m){[36mvar[39m sub[33m=[39m_subscriptions[index][33m;[39m[36mif[39m(isObject_1[33m.[39misObject(sub))[36mtry[39m{sub[33m.[39munsubscribe()}[36mcatch[39m(e){errors[33m=[39merrors[33m||[39m[][33m,[39me [36minstanceof[39m [33mUnsubscriptionError_1[39m[33m.[39m[33mUnsubscriptionError[39m[33m?[39merrors[33m=[39merrors[33m.[39mconcat(flattenUnsubscriptionErrors(e[33m.[39merrors))[33m:[39merrors[33m.[39mpush(e)}}}[36mif[39m(errors)[36mthrow[39m [36mnew[39m [33mUnsubscriptionError_1[39m[33m.[39m[33mUnsubscriptionError[39m(errors)}}[33m,[39m[33mSubscription[39m[33m.[39mprototype[33m.[39madd[33m=[39m[36mfunction[39m(teardown){[36mvar[39m subscription[33m=[39mteardown[33m;[39m[36mif[39m([33m![39mteardown)[36mreturn[39m [33mSubscription[39m[33m.[39m[33mEMPTY[39m[33m;[39m[36mswitch[39m([36mtypeof[39m teardown){[36mcase[39m[32m"function"[39m[33m:[39msubscription[33m=[39m[36mnew[39m [33mSubscription[39m(teardown)[33m;[39m[36mcase[39m[32m"object"[39m[33m:[39m[36mif[39m(subscription[33m===[39m[36mthis[39m[33m||[39msubscription[33m.[39mclosed[33m||[39m[32m"function"[39m[33m!=[39m[36mtypeof[39m subscription[33m.[39munsubscribe)[36mreturn[39m subscription[33m;[39m[36mif[39m([36mthis[39m[33m.[39mclosed)[36mreturn[39m subscription[33m.[39munsubscribe()[33m,[39msubscription[33m;[39m[36mif[39m([33m![39m(subscription [36minstanceof[39m [33mSubscription[39m)){[36mvar[39m tmp[33m=[39msubscription[33m;[39m(subscription[33m=[39m[36mnew[39m [33mSubscription[39m)[33m.[39m_subscriptions[33m=[39m[tmp]}[36mbreak[39m[33m;[39m[36mdefault[39m[33m:[39m[36mthrow[39m [36mnew[39m [33mError[39m([32m"unrecognized teardown "[39m[33m+[39mteardown[33m+[39m[32m" added to Subscription."[39m)}[36mvar[39m _parentOrParents[33m=[39msubscription[33m.[39m_parentOrParents[33m;[39m[36mif[39m([36mnull[39m[33m===[39m_parentOrParents)subscription[33m.[39m_parentOrParents[33m=[39m[36mthis[39m[33m;[39m[36melse[39m [36mif[39m(_parentOrParents [36minstanceof[39m [33mSubscription[39m){[36mif[39m(_parentOrParents[33m===[39m[36mthis[39m)[36mreturn[39m subscription[33m;[39msubscription[33m.[39m_parentOrParents[33m=[39m[_parentOrParents[33m,[39m[36mthis[39m]}[36melse[39m{[36mif[39m([33m-[39m[35m1[39m[33m!==[39m_parentOrParents[33m.[39mindexOf([36mthis[39m))[36mreturn[39m subscription[33m;[39m_parentOrParents[33m.[39mpush([36mthis[39m)}[36mvar[39m subscriptions[33m=[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_subscriptions[33m;[39m[36mreturn[39m [36mnull[39m[33m===[39msubscriptions[33m?[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_subscriptions[33m=[39m[subscription][33m:[39msubscriptions[33m.[39mpush(subscription)[33m,[39msubscription}[33m,[39m[33mSubscription[39m[33m.[39mprototype[33m.[39mremove[33m=[39m[36mfunction[39m(subscription){[36mvar[39m subscriptions[33m=[39m[36mthis[39m[33m.[39m_subscriptions[33m;[39m[36mif[39m(subscriptions){[36mvar[39m subscriptionIndex[33m=[39msubscriptions[33m.[39mindexOf(subscription)[33m;[39m[33m-[39m[35m1[39m[33m!==[39msubscriptionIndex[33m&&[39msubscriptions[33m.[39msplice(subscriptionIndex[33m,[39m[35m1[39m)}}[33m,[39m[33mSubscription[39m[33m.[39m[33mEMPTY[39m[33m=[39m((empty[33m=[39m[36mnew[39m [33mSubscription[39m)[33m.[39mclosed[33m=[39m[33m![39m[35m0[39m[33m,[39mempty)[33m,[39m[33mSubscription[39m}()[33m;[39m[36mfunction[39m flattenUnsubscriptionErrors(errors){[36mreturn[39m errors[33m.[39mreduce(([36mfunction[39m(errs[33m,[39merr){[36mreturn[39m errs[33m.[39mconcat(err [36minstanceof[39m [33mUnsubscriptionError_1[39m[33m.[39m[33mUnsubscriptionError[39m[33m?[39merr[33m.[39merrors[33m:[39merr)})[33m,[39m[])}exports[33m.[39m[33mSubscription[39m[33m=[39m[33mSubscription[39m}[33m,[39mzfKp[33m:[39m[36mfunction[39m(module[33m,[39mexports[33m,[39m__webpack_require__){[32m"use strict"[39m[33m;[39m[33mObject[39m[33m.[39mdefineProperty(exports[33m,[39m[32m"__esModule"[39m[33m,[39m{value[33m:[39m[33m![39m[35m0[39m})[33m,[39mexports[33m.[39mobservable[33m=[39m[32m"function"[39m[33m==[39m[36mtypeof[39m [33mSymbol[39m[33m&&[39m[33mSymbol[39m[33m.[39mobservable[33m||[39m[32m"@@observable"[39m}}])[33m;[39m[0m[0m [90m   |[39m                                                                                                                          [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
at instantiate (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
at constructor (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:366:12)
at Parser.raise (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3453:19)
at Parser.parseExprListItem (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14167:14)
at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13011:22)
at Parser.parseCoverCallAndAsyncArrowHead (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12908:29)
at Parser.parseSubscript (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12833:19)
at Parser.parseSubscripts (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12802:19)
at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12791:17)
at Parser.parseUpdate (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12764:21)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12734:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12525:61)
at Parser.parseExprOps (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12532:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12502:23)
at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12454:21)
at Parser.parseExpressionBase (D:\Code\qat-new-dev\oogyy\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12390:23)
```